# Keep original amount format after ratio multiplication

Tags: sql, oracle, format

I have a problem with format conversion in SQL after a ratio multiplication.

I have several amounts in this form :

```
00000000008846
00000000002258
00000000000003
00000000006088
00000000696714
00000000636292
00000000043845
```

For each amount, I have a ratio currency in this form:

```
000000875000
000001030000
000001512000
000001480000
000000980000
000001950000
```

What I want to do is, after multiplying the amount with the currency, getting back the original amount format.

Currently, I get numbers like this after multiplying:

```
9531000000
8846000000
2258000000
3000000
6088000000
738516840000
655380760000
```

What I want is a 14 digits number like the original ammount:

```
00000000009531
00000000008846
00000000002258
00000000000003
00000000006088
00000000738517
00000000655381
```

You can see the result is rounded for the last 2.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to convert your results back to `varchar2` data type, either by

```
to_char(:your_result_value,'fm00000000000000')
```

or by

```
lpad(:your_result_value, 14, '0')
```

Enjoy.